# Algorithm Analysis Big-O

Tags: python, algorithm

I need some help calculating the Big-O running time.

I have attempted to do it after each problem, but not sure if it's done correctly.

Q-1: Given the following code fragment, what is its Big-O running time?

```
 test = 0

 for i in range(n):

        for j in range(n):

                test= test + i *j
```

T(n)= c1+n*(n)

= c1+n^2

O(n) ≈ n^2

Q-2: Given3 the following code fragment what is its Big-O running time?

```
 for i in range(n):

      test=test+1

 for j in range(n):

      test= test - 2
```

T(n)= c1*n+c2(n*n)

T(n)= c1*n1+c2n^2

O(n) ≈ n^2

Q-3: Given the following code fragment what is its Big-O running time?

```
 i = n

 while i > 0:

        k=2+2

        i = i // 2
```

T(n)= n*(c1+c2)

O(n) ≈n

Comment: One would say `T(n) = O(n^2)`, not `O(n) ≈ n^2` for some (unspecified) function of `n`.

Comment: Your 2nd code snap identation is unclear. Is the 2nd loop nested within the first?

Comment: I would say `O(n^2)`, `O(n)`, and `O(n)` respectively. For Q2 Just because jyou have `2 * O(n)` doesn't make it `O(n^2)`

Comment: @chepner If we're at it, `T(n)` is in `O(n^2)`, since `T(n)` is a function and `O(f(n))` is a set of funcitons/

Comment: @CoryKramer You would be wrong.

Comment: @amit Overloading `=` here is accepted practice.

Comment: @chepner On which of the three questions?

Comment: Thanks for the input! What's the best way to learn it?

Comment: @CoryKramer The third one; `//` is a division operator in Python.

Comment: Why the downvotes?! Just because you know the answer and you've taken computer science courses doesn't mean this isn't a legitimate question. And the OP has clearly tried, with explanation! What more could you want? This site is obnoxious to new users.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Big O, how do you calculate/approximate it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3255/big-o-how-do-you-calculate-approximate-it)

Answer (score 2):

## Q-1

You are right.

`for i in range(n)` is `O(n)`, nesting means multiplication, so `O(n^2)` is right.

## Q-2

No, sequential evaluation is addition, so two loops in a row is `O(n)+O(n)=O(n)`.

## Q-3

No, each iteration *halves* `n`, so the complexity is `O(log(n))`.

Comment: short and to the point

Answer (score 0):

First, let's start with your terminology, `O(n)≈f(n)` is not the right terminology, correct one would be to say `T(n)` is in `O(f(n))`, where `T(n)` is the complexity function of the code, and `f(n)` is the given complexity, so `T(n)` is in `O(n^2)`, for example.

**First code snap:**

 This is indeed O(n^2), your analysis is correct.

**Second code snap:**

<strike>This is O(n^2), assuming the second loop is nested within the first (your identation is not clear), again - your analysis is correct.

If this is not the case, then</strike> these are sequential loops - each is taking `O(n)`, so total complexity is the addition of them, which yields `O(n)` as well.

**Third code snap:**

This is `O(logn)`. Each iteration halves `i` until `i` reaches 0. This happens within `log_2(n)` steps of dividing it by two.

Comment: It's sequential loops for the second case, sorry about that.